# How to get now Year using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

```
var date = '04/04';<br>
alert(new Date(date));<br>

//now year 2013<br>
//result Wed Apr 04 <b>2001</b>
```

I want

```
//result Wed Apr 04 <b>2013</b>
```

Comment: strange (for me) Anyhow, I did something like this to solve it `alert(new Date(date + " " + new Date().getFullYear()));`. Not sure whether it is correct or not though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current date by `new Date();` So current year can be found by:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
  //this would return 2013
```

So following code would do the work for getting correct date:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

var date = "04/04";              //the date entered
var comp = date.split('/');
var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);   //this would give you the entered month
var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);   //this would give you the entered date

var correctDate = new Date(currentYear, m - 1, d);
correctDate.toDateString();   //this line will return the date
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parts individually with the `setX()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nowYear=new Date().getFullYear(); //current year

var date = '04/04/'+nowYear.toString();

alert( new Date(date));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LhXH4/

is that really returning *Wed Apr 04 2001*? instead  of *invalid date*? without year in string , how did it get parsed?

Comment: It is returning 2001.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = '04/04';
date = new Date(date);
date = new Date(2013, date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
alert(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

With static year it will be:

```
var date = '04/04';
alert(new Date('2013/'+date));
```

where date format is `yyyy/MM/dd`